# Looping through POST variables from Form

Tags: php, arrays

I'm sure this is quite simple but all my searches have thrown up complicated answers that don't seem quite on point.

I have an array from a form and want to echo it back to a customer with an option to confirm the order.

The array looks like this:-

```
 POST:- Array
(
    [choice] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 4
                    [price] => 7.50
                    [itemname] => Margherita Pizza
                    [merchant] => 3000
                    [itemid] => 2000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 3.50
                    [itemname] => Garlic Bread
                    [merchant] => 3000
                    [itemid] => 2001
                )

        )

    [submit] => Submit
)
```

and the code I'm using to extract is:-

```
    $_cp_i=0;
    foreach($_POST['choice'] as $mychoice) {
    $itemname[$_cp_i]=$mychoice['itemname'][$_cp_i];
    $quantity[$_cp_i]=$mychoice['quantity'][$_cp_i];
    $price[$_cp_i]=$mychoice['price'][$_cp_i];
    $_cp_i++;
    echo "<tr><td>$itemname</td><td>$quantity[$_cp_i]</td> 
<td>$price[$_cp_i]</td></tr>";
}
```

The itemname just shows as Array and the other two fields are blank.

Comment: Why are you creating that `$itemname`, `$quantity` variables at all? Simple `$mychoice['itemname']` and `$mychoice['quantity']` would do. You don't need that pointless `$_cp_i` variables too. Also please read any good practices how to name variables.

Comment: $_cp_ is a prefix enforced by the framework.

Comment: @Alan Dev - I'm not sure if it is just a Zend coding convention but starting variable or method names with an underscore is generally used to denote a private or protected variable or method.

Comment: @AlanDev  Why this much code if `foreach()` is enough for you:-

`foreach($_POST['choice'] as $mych) {
    echo "<tr><td>". $mych['itemname'] ."</td><td>" . $mych['quantity'] ."</td><td>". $mych['price'] ."</td></tr>";
}`
Output:-https://eval.in/1058779

Comment: I would like this question to be reopened because there was a genuine issue of understanding here and the community provided an answer. I would like others to benefit from the wisdom that was applied to my answer, I've just come here today to look at it again as it is relevant to a similar problem I have encountered and was shocked to see it closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
$_cp_i=0;
foreach($_POST['choice'] as $mychoice) {
    $itemname[$_cp_i] = $mychoice['itemname'];
    $quantity[$_cp_i] = $mychoice['quantity'];
    $price[$_cp_i] = $mychoice['price'];
    echo "<tr><td>{$itemname[$_cp_i]}</td><td>{$quantity[$_cp_i]}</td><td>{$price[$_cp_i]}</td></tr>\n";
    $_cp_i++;
}
```

Output:

```
<tr><td>Margherita Pizza</td><td>4</td><td>7.5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Garlic Bread</td><td>2</td><td>3.5</td></tr>
```

If you don't actually require the data in the `itemname`, `quantity` and `price` arrays elsewhere, you can produce this output with just this simple loop:

```
foreach($_POST['choice'] as $mychoice) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$mychoice['itemname']}</td><td>{$mychoice['quantity']}</td><td>{$mychoice['price']}</td></tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: May be solution is correct, but this much code is not needed at all. simple `foreach()` will do the job

Comment: @AlivetoDie in terms of outputting the table, absolutely. I'm assuming OP has need of those arrays of data elsewhere. I've edited my post with a simple loop solution as well though so OP can have both options.

Comment: Exactly Nick, I stripped it back to the essence of the problem 